# Adjoint of differential operator in two variables

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I would like to find the adjoint of the operator $$L = x \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y^{2}} \frac{\partial }{\partial x}.$$ I know the adjoint is the operator $L^{*}$ such that $$(Lu,v) = (u, L^{*}v)$$ for all $u,v$. 
But here we are dealing with a differential operator in two variables ($x$ and $y$). How can I find $L^{*}$?

Comment: is it $(u,v)=\int \int u(x,y)\overline{v(x,y)} dx dy$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your formulation the problem is not correctly posed. The operator $L$ is
not defined for all $u\in \mathcal{H}=L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2},dxdy)$. But it is
well-defined on a suitable dense set. Let $p_{x}$ and $p_{y}$ the
self-adjoint momentum operators derived from $-i\partial _{x}$ and $%
-i\partial _{y}$. Then on the domain of $xp_{x}p_{y}^{2}$
\begin{equation*}
L=x\partial _{y}^{2}\partial _{x}=x\partial _{x}\partial
_{y}^{2}=-ixp_{x}p_{y}^{2},
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
L^{\ast }=ip_{x}xp_{y}^{2}.
\end{equation*}
For a suitable dense set of $v$'s, such as the compactly supported
infinitely differentiable $v$'s,%
\begin{equation*}
L^{\ast }v=-\partial _{x}x\partial _{y}^{2}v,
\end{equation*}
which can also be obtained by direct partial integration.